# Continuously read the first 3 lines in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.6

I have a huge file from which I want to read the first 3 lines and put them in another file *new.txt*. After that, read again 3 lines but not from the start, it should take the 3 lines starting from the 4th line.

```
 1st line
 2nd line
 3rd line
 4th line
 5th line
 6th line
 7th line
 8th line
 9th line
 10th line
 ....
```

First output in the file new.txt will be:

```
 1st line
 2nd line
 3rd line
```

Second output in the file new.txt will be:

```
4th line
5th line
6th line
```

Comment: Sure, read as you want. What have you tried?

Comment: What do you mean by "Second output in the file new.txt"? Does this overwrite the first output, or append to it? How is this different than simply copying six lines in one go?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this - bear in mind that instead of `i` you can just use the file-obj directly.

```
from itertools import islice

r = range(20)
i = iter(r)

while True:
    lines = list(islice(i, 3))
    if not lines:
        break
    print lines

[0, 1, 2]
[3, 4, 5]
[6, 7, 8]
[9, 10, 11]
[12, 13, 14]
[15, 16, 17]
[18, 19]
```

Comment: @surya Then write the list out...!?

Answer (score 0):

Files are iterators, so all you have to do is group the input by three items each.

The [`iterttools` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) comes with a recipe for grouping iterators:

```
from itertools import izip_longest

def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper(3, 'ABCDEFG', 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)
```

Now you can group your input file lines in bunches of three:

```
with open(inputfilename) as infile:
    for threelines in grouper(3, infile, ''):
        with open(outputfilename, 'w') as outfile:
            outfile.write(''.join(threelines))
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can get the cursor position with 
`f.tell()`

and you can move the cursor to a position within a file with:
`f.seek()`

Check here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek